# JQuery Parse variable into onclick

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I have a bit of Jquery written to add an image with an on click event but I am struggling to get the on click to alert the function that I have created the ultimate aim here is to build a window.open event that uses the lookURL variable as its a address.

To save placing loads of code in the question i have created a JS Fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/justinerswell/qJFUa/5/

Comment: Your jsfiddle example alerts me with "This Works" when I click the image. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I need to parse in the lookURL variable to build a window.open event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely confident I know what you're trying to do but if all you want to do is get the `lookURL` variable into the function that is executed when the `click()` is run, it's pretty easy: http://jsfiddle.net/XcAHx/

I've taken the `onClick` out of the HTML and into it's own function, and in there you can just reference the `lookURL` variable:

```
$("a").bind("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert(lookURL);
});
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Awesome! thanks for that I wonder if you can help with the next bit! I have this field with the id of adds_postcode which is blank on page load i.e no value I then need to capture the user input eg.w10 1fb and use it in the lookURL function any thoughts?

Comment: DUDE you rock!!! I take it its just a case of replacing the alert with window.open?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. The variable `fullURL` stores the URL with postcode, so do with that what you please :)

Answer (score 1):

You've done most of the work, just change

```
alert('This works')
```

to

```
myfunc('" + lookURL + "')
```

[modified jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6xbPr/)

Comment: Hi thanks that works great, have hit another snag now I need to capture the input value after it has been typed by a user any thoughts on how?